# How to use angular $compile with d3.js to manipulate SVG string?

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have a bunch of icons stored as strings.  I am working on a directive to add these basic icons to the DOM, with a few options for manipulation - adding an outline shape, adding/removing fills and strokes, etc.  My directive $observes the element's attributes, updates the scope accordingly.  I am using ng-bind-html inside the template to render the icons.  I'm fairly new to Angular, and this is the most complex issue I've had to solve thus far. I'm using compile like so:

```
    $compile(icon)(scope, function(e,s){
          var svg = d3.select(e).append("circle").attr("r","20");
          ...
    })[0].outerHTML)
```

Am I on the right track?

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cupofnestor/rdhjet8n/)